# sublime text 2 cursor is highlighting the next character... why?

Tags: cursor, settings, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

i fat-fingered something in my editor and i don't know why this is happening!  somebody please help me.

[image: screenshot of my cursor situation.]

Comment: i have quit and restarted the program, looked in the config settings, but nothing looks like it pertains to the cursor.

Comment: Have you installed some package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same problem today.

Problem was definitely the BlockCursor plugin. That somehow got installed w/o me realizing it. I can't believe I fat-fingered enough keystrokes to install that; I would never intentionally install a plugin that did that;) Got installed somehow, tho.

Disabling it fixed problem.

Comment: thanks! i was able to disable the SublimeBlockCursor plugin by going to Preferences > Package Control > Disable Package/s > SublimeBlockCursor

Comment: Wow very glad I found this.  I had the same thing happen to me! I thought it was something I installing on my Ubuntu OS.

Comment: I had to restart after removing. Also for noobs like me... to remove use "Package Control: Remove Package" then seach "BlockCursor" Thanks! +1